# AngularJS. When select have ng-model attribute, ng-selected not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to set `ng-selected` in my `option` element, `selected` attribute is set to `true`, but `option` not selected, When I remove `ng-model` from `select` all become working.

**The question**: How to make `option` selected, when I'm using the model?

Here is [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zgJKbi8DIqamJPmANlrl?p=preview) (`selected` not working here)

My code:

```
var app = angular.module("plunker", []);

app.controller("TestController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.test = 1;
  $scope.array = [
        {"id": 1, "name": "first"}, 
        {"id": 2, "name": "second"}, 
        {"id": 3, "name": "third"}
      ];
}]);
```

My template:

```
  <body ng-controller="TestController">
    Selected item must be {{ array[test-1].name }}
    <select ng-model="myModel">
      <option value="">Choose item..</option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in array" 
              ng-value="item.id" 
              ng-selected="item.id == test">
        {{ item.name }} ({{item.id == test}})
      </option>
    </select>
  </body>
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: ng-selected and ng-model exclude one another. Your model should match the option id

Comment: for select i think you need ng-options https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: once ng-model removed from select. its picking the value to be selected. look at this forked one - http://plnkr.co/edit/u5bYQo7IgNmiABDZSyIQ?p=preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use ngSelected with ngRepeat. Go with ngOptions:

```
  <body ng-controller="TestController">
    Selected item must be {{ array[test-1].name }}
    <select ng-model="myModel" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in array">
      <option value="">Choose item..</option>
    </select>
  </body>
```

Comment: I was about to write this! :P i think this is the correct answer!!

Comment: but what if i have to keep selected value based on ng-repeat value? check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305993/how-to-use-select-inside-ng-repeat-and-keep-value-selected-on-api-call-data?noredirect=1#comment87628318_50305993

Answer (score 2):

### Don't use `ngSelected` with `ngModel`

From the Docs:

> Note: `ngSelected` does not interact with the `<select>` and `ngModel` directives, it only sets the selected attribute on the element. If you are using `ngModel` on the select, **you should not use `ngSelected`** on the options, as `ngModel` will set the select value and selected options.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-selected API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)

See additional Docs:

- [Using `ng-repeat` to generate `select` options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options)
- [Using select with `ng-options` and setting a default value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-select-with-ngoptions-and-setting-a-default-value)

See Stackoverflow:

- [Using `ng-repeat` to generate select options (with Demo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794759/using-ng-repeat-to-generate-select-options/42796398#42796398)