# Using ng-repeat to generate select options (with Demo)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

#### controller:

```
$scope.send_index = function(event, val){ 
    console.log(val);
    $scope.variable = 'vm.areas['+val+'].name';
    console.log( $scope.variable ); 
};
```

and this is in the view:

```
<select ng-model="vm.areas">
    <option ng-repeat="area in vm.areas"  ng-value="area" id="{{area}}" ng-click="send_index($event, $index)">{{area.name}}
</select>
<input value="{{variable}}">
```

where "vm" is my model.

---

#### Expression inside of an expression (Angular)

my problem is that i need to have an {{array[]}}, with the index as another expression,

> e.g: {{Array[{{val}}]}}.

Already tryed this:

```
 $scope.variable = ''+'vm.areas['+val+'].name'+'';
```

The problem is in the view, "variable" is shown like an string

> (vm.areas[0].name)

and it donst get the valor of that query.

Comment: try this  {{Array[val]}}.

Comment: `vm.area[val].name`

Comment: didnt work, keep showing ( vm.area[0].name ) as a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **NOT** the correct way to use `ng-model` with a `<select>` element in AngularJS:

```
<!-- ERRONEOUS
<select ng-model="vm.areas">
    <option ng-repeat="area in vm.areas"  ng-value="area" id="{{area}}" ng-click="send_index($event, $index)">{{area.name}}
</select>

<input value="{{variable}}">
-->
```

There is no need to use the `ng-click` directive. The [select directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) handles that automatically. The `ng-model` directive receives or sets the chosen option.

See:

- [Using `ng-repeat` to generate `select` options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options)
- [Using select with `ng-options` and setting a default value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-select-with-ngoptions-and-setting-a-default-value)

---

```js
angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
     model: null,
     availableOptions: [
       {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
       {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
       {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
     ]
    };
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ngrepeatSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
    <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.model">
      <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>model = {{data.model}}</tt><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `data-ng-value` instead of `value`

```
<input data-ng-value="{{variable}}">
```