# equating variables which are coming from http calls

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-select

I have a select tag with options populated by AngularJS. I am trying to select an option if it equals to another property in scope. Option values and scope property I am trying to compare are both coming from async http call. So there is always delay, then it is not working properly. What is the best practice to make sure that both scope property are resolved and ready to compare.

`ng-selected="MusteriId == option.Value"` is comparing part.

```
<select id="MusteriId" name="MusteriId" ng-model="MusteriId">
    <option ng-selected="MusteriId == option.Value"
            ng-repeat="option in MusteriList" value="{{option.Value}}">
      {{option.Text}}
    </option>
</select>
```

This is my controller where two http calls are performed.

```
(function() {
var biletController = function ($scope, $http, commonFunctions) {

    $scope.Id = null;
    $scope.BiletNo = null;
    $scope.BiletTarihi = null;
    $scope.CurrencyId = null;
    $scope.MusteriId = null;
    $scope.PAID_EUR = null;
    $scope.PAID_TL = null;
    $scope.PAID_USD = null;
    $scope.ServisIstiyorMu = null;
    $scope.TOTAL = null;
    $scope.TourId = null;

    $scope.MusteriList = null;

    $scope.openEditFormJS = function(e) {
        $http.get('/Bilet/Get/' + e)
            .then(function (response) {

                console.log(response.data);

                $scope.Id = response.data.Id;
                $scope.BiletNo = response.data.BiletNo;

                if (response.data.BiletTarihi) {
                    $scope.BiletTarihi = commonFunctions.formatDate(new Date(parseInt(response.data.BiletTarihi.substr(6))));
                }

                $scope.CurrencyId = response.data.CurrencyId;
                $scope.MusteriId = response.data.MusteriId;
                $scope.PAID_EUR = response.data.PAID_EUR;
                $scope.PAID_TL = response.data.PAID_TL;
                $scope.PAID_USD = response.data.PAID_USD;
                $scope.ServisIstiyorMu = response.data.ServisIstiyorMu;
                $scope.TOTAL = response.data.TOTAL;
                $scope.TourId = response.data.TourId;

                $('#modal').modal('show');

            });

        $http.get('/Bilet/GetMusteriSelectList')
            .then(function (response) {

                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.MusteriList = response.data;
            });
    };

};

app.controller('BiletController', ['$scope', '$http', 'commonFunctions', biletController]);
}());
```

Comment: To better understand the problem, I need to see an example of the `response.data` from both $http requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use the `ng-value` directive for non-string values<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50805764/5535245)</sup>

```
<select id="MusteriId" name="MusteriId" ng-model="MusteriId">
    <option ̶n̶g̶-̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶=̶"̶M̶u̶s̶t̶e̶r̶i̶I̶d̶ ̶=̶=̶ ̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶V̶a̶l̶u̶e̶"̶
            ng-repeat="option in MusteriList" ng-value="option.Value">
      {{option.Text}}
    </option>
</select>
```

For more information, see [Using `ngValue` to bind the model to an array of objects](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options)

---

### Don't use `ngSelected` with `ngModel`<sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51014228/5535245)</sup>

```
<select id="MusteriId" name="MusteriId" ng-model="MusteriId">
    <option ̶n̶g̶-̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶=̶"̶M̶u̶s̶t̶e̶r̶i̶I̶d̶ ̶=̶=̶ ̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶V̶a̶l̶u̶e̶"̶
            ng-repeat="option in MusteriList" value="{{option.Value}}">
      {{option.Text}}
    </option>
</select>
```

From the Docs:

> Note: `ngSelected` does not interact with the `<select>` and `ngModel` directives, it only sets the selected attribute on the element. If you are using `ngModel` on the select, **you should not use `ngSelected`** on the options, as `ngModel` will set the select value and selected options.
>
> — [AngularJS ng-selected API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)

See additional Docs:

- [Using `ng-repeat` to generate `select` options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options)
- [Using select with `ng-options` and setting a default value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-select-with-ngoptions-and-setting-a-default-value)

See Stackoverflow:

- [Using `ng-repeat` to generate select options (with Demo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794759/using-ng-repeat-to-generate-select-options/42796398#42796398)

---

Comment: Thanks you, your solution works only if I convert MusteriId result from http response to String. Do you have any suggestion if I can implement something that http results to be converted to string automatically. This is what I used> $scope.MusteriId = String(response.data.MusteriId);

Comment: Did you use `value="{{option.Value}}"` or `ng-value="option.Value"`?

Comment: I used ng-value="option.Value" as you advised. It is working fine but it is sensitive to Data Type, string or number. I should use conversion to String to make it work and it makes sense.

Comment: The `<select>` directive uses strict equality (`===`) when comparing `ng-model` to the value property. This means that `true`,`"true"`,`0`,`false`,`"0"`,`77`,and `"77"` can all have separate select options. If one server request returns numerical ids and the other request returns string ids, that was an unfortunate design decision by the backend coders.