# How to use select inside ng-repeat and keep value selected on api call data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using select inside ng-repeat. I am trying to map value coming from my api to select as selected value. I don't know what's wrong going from my side, please correct me.
Here is [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oj46n6a5/)

HTML code

```
 <div ng-repeat="trip in trips">
        {{trip.type}}
                    <select ng-change="typeChanged(selectedType,trip.id)" id="" name="" ng-model="selectedType">
<option    ng-selected="trip.type === t" ng-repeat="t in tripTypes">{{t}}</option>
</select>
      </div>
```

JS code

```
$scope.trips=[];
  $scope.trips=[{id:1,type:'confirmed'},{id:2,type:'cancelled'}];

      $scope.tripTypes=['Confirmed','Quotation'];
```

Comment: In your JSFiddle, you have selected angular version 1.0.3. I changed it into 1.2.1 and it works fine.

Comment: OK but i am using 1.6 latest with that also it is not working

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. It works in the JSFiddle. The syntax looks fine. You must have a typo or something in your actual code.

Comment: Use common comparison instead of strict comparison in `ng-selected`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making so silly mistake i guess because after doing below changes my code worked, i changed ng-model to trip.type from selectedType, so only it is possible for ng-selected to check condition.

```
<div ng-repeat="trip in trips">
{{trip.type}}
<select ng-change="typeChanged(selectedType,trip.id)" id="" name="" ng-model="trip.type">
<option    ng-selected="trip.type === t" ng-repeat="t in tripTypes">{{t}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Here is working fiddle [Check now](http://jsfiddle.net/0hydq142/)