# Drop down default value select based on condition

Tags: angularjs, select, drop-down-menu

Issues fiddle here [dropdown issue with default selection](http://jsfiddle.net/z2mw1fsk/5/)
Below the JSON used to populate the drop down.

```
        {
            "key": "all",
            "value": "First",
            "default":"N"
        },       
        {
            "key": "only_my_events",
            "value": "Default",
            "default":"Y"
        },
        {
            "key": "only_assigned",
            "value": "Second",
            "default":"N"
        },
        {
            "key": "only_owner",
            "value": "Third",
            "default":"N"
        },
        {
            "key": "none",
            "value": "Fourth",
            "default":"N"
        }
```

Drop down code to display the item

```
 <select ng-model="mail_notification" ng-options="c.key as c.value for c in mail_notifications" ng-init = "c.default = 'Y'"></select>
```

**Required**

The default item selected should be the item with default value is  Y (default = 'Y').

**Issues.**

First item in the drop down is empty. there is no default selected item.

**Already tried.**

Seen solution like setting a default value like " Choose an Item", which is not im looking for.
[AngularJS. When select have ng-model attribute, ng-selected not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996714/angularjs-when-select-have-ng-model-attribute-ng-selected-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, you just need to set the ng-model as  **mail_notification**

```
$scope.setDefault = function(){
  $scope.mail_notification = $scope.mail_notifications.find(t=>t.default === 'Y').key;
  console.log($scope.mail_notification);
}
```

and in HTML

```
  <select ng-model="mail_notification" ng-options="c.key as c.value for c in mail_notifications" ng-init = "setDefault()"></select>
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d4p9haet/)**

Comment: This is hard coded. Looking for dynamic solution, I need to set using <select>. using ng-init or ng-selected.

Comment: even if you use ng-init its hardcoding dude

Comment: That is the requirement, default = Y. That should be the condition. Can't set json value directly, that will be dynamic.