# How to use ng-select with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a code where I am using ng-repeat to iterate over options. now I want to use ng-select to select some value with a given condition but as the AngularJS docs mention :

> ngSelected does not interact with the select and ngModel directives,
>   it only sets the selected attribute on the element. If you are using
>   ngModel on the select, you should not use ngSelected on the options,
>   as ngModel will set the select value and selected options.

but as the structure of the ng-repeat is like the given below:

```
  <select name="selectedPerson" id="selectedPerson" class="form-control"  ng-model="selectedPerson" >
   <option value="-1">Select Person</option>
   <option ng-repeat="name in nameList" value="{{name.id}}" >{{name.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

I can not use ng-select in the select.
Now I do not want to iterate over a long list and compare the value with the condition and then set it in ng-model.
I think the problem may get solved with using ng-options, but what I still know about ng-model is that it set complete object in ng-model, which I do not want, as because of that I may need to change a large amount of code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS. When select have ng-model attribute, ng-selected not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996714/angularjs-when-select-have-ng-model-attribute-ng-selected-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

```
<option ng-model="value" ng-repeat="name in nameList" value="{{name.id}}" >{{name.name}}</option>
```

add `ng-model` to your option line

you now have the data which you can access from your scope